# What do the local sections of an nilpotent ideal sheaf look like?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(X, O_X)$ be a scheme. and $I$ an nilptoent ideal sheaf. i.e. $I^n=0$ for some $n$. Would this imply that each $I(U)$ is an nilpotent ideal of $O_X(U)$?

Comment: What does $I^n = 0$ mean if it doesn't mean that $I(U)^n = 0$ for all $U$?

Comment: For me $I^n$ is the sheafification of $U \mapsto I(U)^n$.

Comment: If a presheaf is zero, then it's sheafification is zero, right? I guess like Qiaochu I'm having trouble seeing where your issues are.

Comment: @KReiser this goes the other way, if I'm not mistaken. In this case, the sheafification is zero, which I believe need not imply that the original presheaf is zero. But maybe I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: If a presheaf is separated and has zero sheafification, it’s zero, right? Well, isn’t $U\mapsto I(U)^n$ a subhseaf of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis You mean subpresheaf, right?

Comment: @AlexYoucis very nice! I was hoping there would be a straightforward way to see that there's no weirdness with local vanishing, and your argument indeed shows that nothing pathological can happen.

Comment: @Stahl Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m submitting this as an alternative to **hm2020**’s answer. It’s an elaboration of what I wrote in the comments.

Let $I\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ be an ideal sheaf, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the presheaf assigning to each open subset $U$ of $X$ the ideal $I(U)^n\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. You say that $I$ is *nilpotent of degree $n$* if $\mathcal{F}^\#$ is zero, where $\#$ is used to denote sheafification. But, since $\mathcal{F}$ is a separated presheaf, being a subsheaf of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, one has that $\mathcal{F}=0$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}^\#=0$ (e.g. see [1, Tag00WB]). Thus, we deduce the following:

> **Fact:** Let $X$ be a scheme and $I$ an ideal sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$. Then, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. For all open subsets $U$ the ideal $I(U)^n$ is zero.
> 2. The sheafification of the presheaf $U\mapsto I(U)^n$ is zero.

[1] Various authors, 2020. *Stacks project*. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/

Answer (score 1):

Given a quasi coherent sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ where $X$ is a scheme, we get a presheaf

$\mathcal{I}(n)(U):=\{ \sum_I s_Ix_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_n}: x_{i_j}\in \mathcal{I}(U)$ and $s_I\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)\} \subseteq \mathcal{I}(U)$

If $U_i:=Spec(A_i)$ and $\mathcal{I}(U_i):=I_i \subseteq A_i$ it follows
by definition

$\mathcal{I}(n)(U_i):=I_i^n.$

Definition 0. Let $\mathcal{I}^n:=\mathcal{I}(n)^{+}$ be the sheafification of $\mathcal{I}(n)$. It follows there is a canonical injective map of sheaves

$\mathcal{I}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{I}$.

It follows $\mathcal{I}^n(U_i)=I^n_i$.

Definition 1. Let us define a quasi coherent sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I}$ to be "nilpotent" iff there is an integer $n\geq 1$ with $\mathcal{I}^n(U)=0$ for all open sets $U$.

If $I \subseteq A$ is an ideal with $I^n=0$ and $\mathcal{I}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ with $X:=Spec(A)$ is the corresponding sheaf of ideals, it follows $\mathcal{I}^n(X)\cong I^n=0$. You may moreover prove that there is a canonical isomorphism

I1. $\mathcal{I}(U)\cong \mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes_A I \rightarrow^j  \mathcal{O}_X(U)$

where the map $j$ is the canonical map

$j(u\otimes x):= ux$.

Here $u\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and $x\in I$. The map $j$ is an injective map since the ring extension $A \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is flat for any open set $U$. Hence the injective map $j$ is obtained from the inclusion $I \subseteq A$ via tensor product.

Note: To prove that the canonical map $A\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is flat
you should use an exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald (Ex 4.23) where you give an alternative construction of the structure sheaf. You define

$\mathcal{O}_X(U) :=lim_{D(f) \subseteq U}\mathcal{O}_X(D(f)):= lim_{D(f) \subseteq U}A_f$.

Since $A\rightarrow A_f$ is flat, it follows $A\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is flat since it is a direct limit of flat maps.

Note: I want to recommend the exercise in AM since it gives an alternative construction of the structure sheaf of a scheme.

If you choose arbitrary elements

$w_1:=u_1\otimes x_1,...,w_n:=u_n\otimes x_n$ in $\mathcal{I}(U)$ it follows

$w_1\cdots w_n = u_1\cdots u_nx_1\cdots x_n=0$ since $x_1\cdots x_n=0$ in $I^n=0$.

and from I1 it follows $\mathcal{I}^n(U)=0$.

Question: "Would this imply that each $I(U)$ is an nilpotent ideal of $O_X(U)$?"

Answer: It seems like the answer is "yes" by the above argument, but there may of course be errors.

Conversely if $\mathcal{I}^n(U)=0$ for all open sets $U$ it follows in particular that $\mathcal{I}^n(X)=I^n =0$.

It seems: In the affine situation it follows the quasi coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ is nilpotent (in the sense of Definition 1) iff the ideal $I$ is nilpotent.

Example: The general case. You must be more careful when $X$ is no longer an affine scheme. The correspondence between ideal sheaves $\mathcal{I}$ and ideals $I \subseteq S$ when $S$ is a graded ring and $X:=Proj(S)$ is more complicated (see Hartshorne Exercise II.5.9).

It seems we should give the following  general definition for a quasi coherent sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I}$ to be nilpotent:

Definition 2. The quasi coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ is nilpotent iff there is an integer $n \geq 1$ with $\mathcal{I}^n_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$
in $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}}$ for every point $\mathfrak{p}$.

It seems to me Definition 2 agrees with Definition 1 in the affine situation but you have to check this.